# python selenium - how can I get all visible text on the page (i.e., not the page source)

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting all visible text from a webpage using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947579/getting-all-visible-text-from-a-webpage-using-selenium)

I would like to search for the occurrence of a particular string on a set of webpages.  However, I don't care if this string occurs in the source code of the page.  I only care whether this string occurs in such a way that a user would come across it if they were viewing the site.  How can I get all the text on the page that might actually be visible in the browser?  Something like the combination of the `text` of every element on the page, probably.

Comment: possible dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947579/getting-all-visible-text-from-a-webpage-using-selenium

Comment: thanks -- there seems to be a possible solution at that link.

Comment: Sometime I wonder how much effort some people are putting into searching for any solution before posting the question...

Comment: @AlexOkrushko -- not that I never do it, but if it is a specific topic that you are interested in, it happens, that you have already seen it.